# How to async add data (needs to iterate twice) to API service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I have a json file like below:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "person1",
      "information": [
        {
        "first_name": "Mike",
        "last_name": "Patty",
        "address": ["address1","address2"]
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Mike2",
          "last_name": "Patty2",
          "address": ["address1","address2"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "person2",
      "information": [
        {
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "last_name": "Jerry",
        "address": ["address1","address2"]
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Tom2",
          "last_name": "Jerry2",
          "address": ["address1","address2"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**I would like to iterate users and add each user's information to the API database. `addInfo` request requires: `first_name`, `last_name` and `address` (`address` is array). It is because I need to save response from information request for later use**. I am pretty new to angular/typescript. So here is what I am trying to code so far:

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That JSON you provide in the post is not valid. That is going to make answering your question difficult.

Comment: Sorry about this. I have fixed the json file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

forkjoin need an array of observables, execute the observables, and, when all the onbservables are completed return the response of each one. So you should create this array of observables. For this, you convert your array "users" in an array of call API. For this you use "map" (is the "map of an array")

```
const addUsers$ = forkJoin(
User.map(x=>
  //each "x" is in the way {id:..,information:{first_name:..,last_name:..,address:..}
  this.APIservice.addInformation(
           {
              firstName: x.information.first_name,
              lastName: x.information.last_name,
              organizations: x.information.address
           }
      )).subscribe((res:any[])=>{
            //in res[0] you has the response to the first call API, 
            //in res[1] you has the response to the second one
            //...

      })
```

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo.  `x.Information` has multiple elements. I think I need to add `x.information.map(ppl => {`  to make codes run. If I just `return res` ? and then run `mergeAll(() => addUsers$)`, it gives me error: `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Try `flatMap`

```
const addUsers$ = forkJoin(
     Users.flatMap(user => user.information).map(info => 
       this.APIservice.addInformation(
           {
              firstName: info.first_name,
              lastName: info.last_name,
              organizations: info.address
           }
      )))
   );
```

Comment: Thanks @MoxxiManagarm. I cannot import `flatMap` using `import { mergeMap, tap, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`: `'flatMap' is deprecated.ts(6385)
mergeMap.d.ts(37, 4): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.`

Comment: flatMap is a function of the array, not an rxjs operator here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap